# List of unsatisfiable cores?

Tags: satisfiability

Is there a place I can find a list of known unsatisfiable cores for X variables [no more then 10] in CNF format?

Or is there an 'easy' way to find out, say I have 7 variables how many clauses [of the 7 variables] do I need for an unsatisfiable cores.

[I calculated 2-5 by hand, I am just trying to figure out 6+].

Thanks

Staque

Comment: I think the tag of this question is improper. Please change the tag of this question.

Comment: What is a core?

Comment: @DanielV: a subset of clauses whose conjunction is still unsatisfiable is called an unsatisfiable core of the original formula.

Comment: @AxelKemper Does that also require that a core doesn't have a subset of unsatisfiable clauses?  Is everyone saying CNF when they mean 3-CNF?

Comment: @DanielV: An unsatisfiable core is called "minimal", if none of its clauses can be removed without making it satisfiable. In other words: Not all unsatisfiable cores have this property. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsatisfiable_core

Comment: @AxelKemper Thank you Axel.

Comment: @DanielV: CNF is not restricted to clauses with three literals. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

The potential number of pairwise different clauses with $n$ variables and the number of sorted sets of clauses:

[image]

Your proposed list of unsatisfiable cores is intractable long for any meaningful number of variables.

A brute-force way to find such unsatisfiable cores would be to enumerate the sets with a given number of variables and clauses. To be an unsatisfiable core, the set of clauses has to be unsatisfiable as a whole. This can be checked by using a SAT solver or enumerating up to $2^n$ variable assignments.

Unsatisfiable cores are usually created or extracted with respect to a given Boolean formula rather than compiling a complete list of all conceivable cores.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking has been dealt with in the literature, and there is even a system that does it. Here is an example: https://sun.iwu.edu/~mliffito/publications/jar_liffiton_CAMUS.pdf